# Swift unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on let variable

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am fairly new to iOS development. I can’t figure out what I am doing wrong for the life of me. I am getting the

> “Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_l386_NVOP, subcode=0x0)”

error with the menCalories variable. In the debugger I am getting the error:

> “fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Here is my code. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
@IBAction func calculate(sender: AnyObject) {

    var ageInt:Int? = age.text!.toInt()
    var weightInt:Int? = weightLabel.text!.toInt()
    var heightInt:Int? = height.text!.toInt()

    if gender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

        let menCalories:Double = 66.47 + (13.75 * Double(weightInt!)) + (5.0 * Double(heightInt!)) - (6.75 * Double(ageInt!))

        calories.text = "\(menCalories)"

    }

    if gender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

    }

}
```

Comment: also make sure your segmented control is connected as a @IBOutlet weak va

Answer (score 2):

> “fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

This happens when the `Optional` doesn't have any value.

What you need to do is check that the variable is not `nil` before you unwrap it.

For example, assumming `ageInt` is the `Optional` with the `nil` value:

```
if ageInt != nil {
    // Do Something
}
```

Or safely unwrapping the value with an `if let` statement:

```
if let safeAgeInt = ageInt {
   // Do Something with safeAgeInt
}
```